# Character count not working for dynamic inputs

Tags: jquery

I know a similar question has been asked but I have been unable to properly implement a working solution yet.  Here is the JS Fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/efA6C/

Here is the html code

```
    <body>

<div id="formula1">
<form>
  <div id="title"> <span>Title</span><input type="text" maxlength="85" size="60"> <input id="random" type="checkbox" style="float:right;"><span style="float:right"> Random? </span><br><br></div>
  <span>Add</span><input type="number" id="addquant" min="1" max="95"><button type="button" class="addmore">More Entries</button>
  <span>Remove</span><input type="number" id="delquant" min="1" max="95"><button type="button" class="delmany">Entries</button>
  <br><br>
  <button type="button" class="preview">Preview</button>
</form>
</div>

<div id="iddisplay"></div>

</body>
```

And here is the script

```
var entlim = 10; // The maximum number of thoughts
var charlim = 10; // The maximum number of characters in each entry

// These are the insert variables when adding new entries
var ins1 = "<div id='temp' class='entry'>";
var ins2 = "<span class='label'> pi. </span>";
var ins3 = "<input type='text' class='entinput' maxlength='" + charlim + "' size='90'> <button type='button' class='entDelete'> Delete </button> ";
var ins4 = "<button type='button' class='entAdd'> Add above </button>";
var ins5 = "<span class='photo'>Add photo?<input class='pic' type='checkbox'></span><br><span class='countdown' style='font-size:12px;left:18px;position:relative'></span><br></div>";
var ins6 = ins1 + ins2 + ins3 + ins4 + ins5;

// Adds individual entries above the clicked button
function addAbove(abo){
  var count = $('div.entry:last').attr('id');
  count = count.replace(/\D/g,'');
  count = parseInt(count);
  if (count >= entlim) {  // Make sure the limit of entries hasn't been reached
    alert("Too many thoughts!");}
  else {
    $(abo).before(ins6);}
    }

// Renumbers all entries sequentially (id's and text label all updated)
function setDivIDs()
  {
  $.each($('form>div.entry'), function(ind,val){
    var num = ind + 1;
    $(this).attr('id', 'ent' + num);
    $(this).find('span.label').html(num + '. ');
    });
  }

function updateCountdown()
  {
  $.each($('form>div.entry'), function(){
    var remaining = charlim - $(this).children('.entinput').val().length;
    if (remaining <= 10 && remaining > 0) {
      $(this).children('span.countdown').text(remaining).css("color","orange");
      }
    else if (remaining === 0) {
      $(this).children('span.countdown').text(remaining).css("color","red");
      }
    else {
      $(this).children('span.countdown').text('');
      }
    });
  }

// Buttons activated after the page has fully loaded
$(document).ready(function(){

  //Build entries (executes one time)
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    $('#title').after(ins6);
    }
  setDivIDs();

  // Add individual entry activation
  $('form').on('click', '.entAdd', function(){
    addAbove($(this).parent());
    setDivIDs();
    updateCountdown();
  });

  // Delete individual entry activation 
  $('form').on('click', '.entDelete', function(){
    $(this).parent().remove();
    setDivIDs();
    if ($('.entry').length < 5) // Make sure that at least 5 entries show at all times
      {
      $('div.entry:last').after(ins6);
      setDivIDs();
      updateCountdown();
      }
  });

  // Add more entries based on user input (limit number of entries)
  $('form').on('click', '.addmore', function(){
    var num = $("#addquant").val();
    for (var i = 0; i < num; i++){
      var count = $('div.entry:last').attr('id');
      count = count.replace(/\D/g,'');
      count = parseInt(count);

      if (count < entlim) 
        {
        $('div.entry:last').after(ins6);
        setDivIDs();
        }
      else
        {
        alert("Too many Entries");
        break;
        }
        $('#addquant').val('');}
    });

  // Delete many entries based on user input (need to limit number deletes)
  $('form').on('click', '.delmany', function(){
    var num = $("#delquant").val();

    for (var i = 0; i < num; i++)
      {
      if ($('.entry').length > 5) 
        {
        $('div.entry:last').remove();
        $('#delquant').val('');
        }
      else
        {
        break;
        }
      } 
    });

   // Update the character countdown
   updateCountdown();
   $.each($('form>div.entry'), function(){
     $(this).children('input').change(updateCountdown);
     $(this).children('input').keyup(updateCountdown);
     });

   // Create upload button for photo uploaded  
   $('form').on('click', '.pic', function(){
     if (this.checked) {
     var count = $(this).parents('div').attr('id');
     count = count.replace(/\D/g,'');
     count = parseInt(count);
     var picins = "<input type='file' id='pic" + count + "'><button type='button' class='rempic'>Remove</button>";
     $(this).parent('span').html(picins);
     };});

   // Remove photo upload button and revert back
   $('form').on('click', '.rempic', function(){
     var addp = "Add photo?<input class='pic' type='checkbox'>";
     $(this).parent('span').html(addp);
     });
});
```

As you can see, the character count works just fine for the initially created entries, however, if you click "add above" and then type into the new entry field, the character count doesn't update until you leave the input.

From what I've gathered, I need to use `.on` but I've been unable to do it properly obviously.

Comment: You have to delegate onchange/onkeyup events too like you do for click event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your event is not getting automatically bound to the new elements.. to do this use delegation like A.Wolff suggested:

I have created this fiddle from your code:

http://jsfiddle.net/jFIT/v8ZMp/

This will automatically bind any text input with class .entinput that exists within your form with a keyup event that calls updateCountdown.

```
$('form').on('keyup', '.entinput', function(){
   updateCountdown(); 
});
```

Comment: Once again, you've come to the rescue @JF it, thanks again for the help.  I was actually pretty close to the solution, my mistake was using 'change' instead of 'keyup'.  Thank you again!

Comment: Yep NP Again @MikelG :) - I use key up for any input types where the user types, and change only for dropdowns/selects. more reliable that way but yes you were very close :)